# How do I make the Visual Studio work with a single-compilation unit?

Tags: visual-studio

By default, Visual Studio compiles all *.cpp files separately. What I am looking for is a way to make Visual Studio use a single-compilation unit for compilation and intellisense.

Comment: @HansPassant - this is to satisfy my curiosity which makes my question valid. People might have different reasons to use SCU and try to google a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has a feature called **Unity (JUMBO) Build** which makes the compiler produce a single object file from all `*.cpp` files.

To enable it, do the following:

1. Go to your solution's properties (`Project > SOLUTION NAME Properties` or Alt+F7)
2. Go to `Configuration Properties > Advanced` and set `Enable Unity (JUMBO) Build` to `Yes`.

Now the project should be compiled using a single-compilation unit.

Answer (score -1):

what is it? Cause it will not work the same for a website than a video game.
cpp files are supposed to be linked,i don't know when there is more than 2. Whatever, the first step is what is your main file. Do you have frameworks for that?

#include "frac.cpp"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).